# Как вызвать RouteBuilder из Processor

Tags: camel

изучаю Camel и столкнулся с проблемой, как из метода process вызвать маршрут нужный? Использую Java JSL.
Есть класс

```
public class PaysRoutBuilder extends Environement {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    getPropertiesComponent();

    /* Get token */
    from("timer:gettoken?period=20000")
            .process(getAuthTokenProcessor)
            .to("direct:ssoCall");

    from("timer:name?period=20000&fixedRate=true")
            .process(searchClientsPropProc)
            .choice().when(exchangeProperty(Start.title))
            .process(getDBDocumentsProc);
```

Класс Environement

```
public abstract class Environement extends RouteBuilder {
   Processor searchClientsPropProc = new SearchClientPropsProc();
   Processor getDBDocumentsProc = new GetDBDocsProc();
   Processor getAuthTokenProcessor = new PrepareAuthTokenHeaders();
}
```

Есть класс добавление роутеров

```
public class Setup {

public Main setup(String... args) throws IOException {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.enableHangupSupport();

    RouteBuilder paysBuilder = new PaysRoutBuilder();

    main.addRouteBuilder(paysBuilder);
    main.addRouteBuilder(new SsoCallRoute());

    return main;
}
}
```

Вот при определенных условиях, мне нужно повторно вызвать маршрут "timer:gettoken" в процессоре getDBDocumentsProc.

Я не могу понять как это сделать, пробовал разные способы, последний такой, никак не могу найти как сделать((

```
new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("time:name").to("time:gettoken");
            }
        };
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вызываются роутеры в процессорах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer самостоятельный потребитель, его вызывать не нужно. Выдели обработку в отдельный маршрут(как бы метод). Тогда его будет вызывать таймер и твой код когда тебе это будет нужно.

```
   /* Get token */
    from("timer:gettoken?period=20000")
            .to("direct:processToken");

    from("direct:processToken")
            .process(getAuthTokenProcessor)
            .to("direct:ssoCall");
```

Как вызвать подмаршрут смотри [тут](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html). Если методы в getAuthTokenProcessor непотокобезопасные лучше используй seda(вместо direct) компонент и настрой обработку в 1 поток.